# Python unittest - get TestCase id's from nested TestSuite

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I have a `unittest.TestSuite` instance.  It is a tree of nested TestSuite/TestCase objects (of arbitrary shape/depth).

I want to get a list of individual test id's contained in the entire suite, without actually running the tests.  (similar to nose's "--collect-only" option).

do i need to recursively walk the `TestSuite`, or is there something in `unittest` I can re-use?
any tips for approaching this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, this works great:

via [testtools](https://github.com/testing-cabal/testtools/blob/master/testtools/testsuite.py#L24):

```
def iterate_tests(test_suite_or_case):
    """Iterate through all of the test cases in 'test_suite_or_case'."""
    try:
        suite = iter(test_suite_or_case)
    except TypeError:
        yield test_suite_or_case
    else:
        for test in suite:
            for subtest in iterate_tests(test):
                yield subtest
```

you can use `testtools.testsuite.iterate_tests(suite)` to iterate over the nested suite.
for example, get a list of test id's, using a list comprehension:

```
[test.id() for test in testtools.testsuite.iterate_tests(suite)]
```